# Is the overall force of a test charge in a electromagnetic field always the same?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields

I had a conversation with my physics teacher today about electric fields and he told me something I couldn't believe and because I found no information elsewhere I am going to ask you guys.

Imagine a radially symmetric electric field like this:

[image]

The inner circle is positive and the outer ring is negative (or the other way around)

Imagine putting a test charge near the middle of the field and measure/calculate its force (lets call it $f_1$) and you putting another test charge near the outer ring and measure/calculate its force (lets call it $f_2$) would $f_1=f_2$, $f_1>f_2$ or $f_1<f_2$?

I am talking about the overall force not the force between the test charge and the minus/positive charged ring or circle

Comment: I don't think this fits into homework-and-excercises.  The poster is asking a conceptual question.  He could improve it by telling us what he concludes from his own knowledge, and how it differs from his teacher's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result that is most relevant here for understanding this is [Gauss' Law](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Gauss%27s_law).  Gauss' Law says in particular that the electric field 'through' a surface (i.e. the flux) depends only upon (and in fact is proportional to) the charge contained inside the surface.  Here this implies that the force on a test charge inside the outer shell does not depend at all on the charge on the outer shell.  In fact, if the total charge in the inner shell is $q$, then for a point in between the shells a distance $r$ from the center, the electric field will be
$$
\frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon _0}\frac{q}{r^2}\hat{\mathbb{r}}.
$$
Thus, $f_2<f_1$ (because $r_2>r_1$, where $r_2$ is the distance the charge near the outer shell is from the center and $r_1$ is the distance the charge in the middle is from the center).